# How to display UI5 sap.ui.core.HTML. setContent is not working

Tags: html, sapui5

I am trying to display a simple HTML content using sap.ui.core.HTML. But I am getting a syntax error in browser. Below is my code and also attached error image. An example of XML view with dynamically setting the content would be greatly helpful.

Thanks,
Srini.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>

    <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
    </script>


    <script>
    var oHtml = new sap.ui.core.HTML("l1"); 
    oHtml.setContent("&lt;h1&gt; This is the simple&lt;/h1&gt; ",true);


    //Create a panel instance
    var oPanel = new sap.ui.commons.Panel();
    //Add something to the panel's content area
    oPanel.addContent(oHtml);
    //Attach the panel to the page
    oPanel.placeAt("content");


    </script>

    </head>
     <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
         <div id="content"></div>   
      </body>
   </html>
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter string passed to `setContent` must contain valid HTML code beginning and ending with a tag. In your case, this is not so, because the HTML syntax is escaped. Just use the HTML syntax unescaped.

```
oHtml.setContent("<h1>This is the simple</h1>");
```

From the [sap documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.HTML.html#setContent):

> The content is converted to DOM nodes with a call to new
>   jQuery(content), so any restrictions for the jQuery constructor apply
>   to the content of the HTML control as well.
>
> Some of these restrictions (there might be others!) are:
>
> - the content must be enclosed in tags, pure text is not supported.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing. It is working now. Just for reference to beginners in UI5, I have created an example http://jsbin.com/gifavu/edit?html,output